# Updating Photo in Curl PHP

Tags: php, api, rest, curl, socialengine

I'm trying to update a profile photo in a REST API using CURL PHP, but it seems not working, it returns null instead of successful message. 
here's my code:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" value="Post" />
</form>

 <?php
    if(isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){
        $curl = curl_init();
        $cfile=new CURLFile($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['image']['type'],$_FILES['image']['name']);
        $data=http_build_query(array("myimage"=>$cfile));
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "http://xxxxx.ph/socialengine/socialapi/member/post/profilePhoto?apiKey=12345678&secretKey=12345679&version=1.0&userId=1",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD=> false,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "cache-control: no-cache",
                "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001",
                "postman-token: 1f21a6a9-8b25-0f68-0231-72466dede66a"
            ),
        ));
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        if ($err) {
            echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
            echo $response;
        }
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: I could very well be mistaken, but using `http_build_query` doesn't seem right.

Comment: I will have the error "Array to string conversion" if I try to remove it..

Comment: What version of PHP is this? Which line is the error occurring on?

Comment: I see where I think that warning is coming from, since you're doing a POST request, do you really need the `&data=".$data."` on the end of the URL?

Comment: i just forgot to remove data=".$data.", I just tried to put it in the URL..

Comment: There is no error occurring, it just returning a null, and nothing happens to the application(SocialEngine) i am trying to update the photo..

Comment: What does `var_dump(curl_getinfo($curl));` give you after the request?

Comment: Errors here:   Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT in /var/www/ph/rd/functions.php on line 48                                              Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE in /var/www/ph/rd/functions.php on line 49

Comment: Don't know if it will make a difference or not but add this to your curl options array `CURLOPT_POST => 1` it is shown in the example on https://wiki.php.net/rfc/curl-file-upload

Comment: Also example does not use `http_build_query()`